# Linq to Sql Update not working

Tags: linq

I have somewhere around 20 tables that I am working with. I can update the User table just fine, however, when I try to update my Address table, nothing happens. I don't receive an exception and the method looks like it executes ok but when I check my data, the values are still the same.

I'm thinking that it has to do with the fact that I moved my database out from under a server and onto my local SQL lite instance. I did change the connection strings in the config and thought that it would take care of the problem (as i stated, I can still select from all of the tables using linq). Has anyone encountered this before or have some idea of what might be going on?

Edit 1 - I'm not very familiar with relocating databases with linq. I do know that SQLMETAL, when I run it, removes all of the customization that i have done inside of my datacatalog. Does just changing the connection in the config work or do I actually have to use SQLMETAL every time the db moves (the structure doesn't change)

Comment: Can you verify before the SubmitChanges() that the change set includes the update that you're expecting?

Comment: Yes. I inspected the values and it does include the changes the i am expecting. i also changed an address value directly in the database and it appeared on my page so I am hitting the correct instance.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this I had to hand modify the constructor to use a different connection string in the File that Visual Studio generates for your instance of the database. I had the same issue as you did and this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Can i ask what modifications you made? I have insepected the connection string for the datacontext at run time on both select and update and it appears to be correct.